# Singleton behavior not achieved

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a @Component like below:

```
@Component
public class FilenetConnection {

    @Value("${filenet.url}")
    String url;
    @Value("${filenet.username}")
    String username;
    @Value("${filenet.password}")
    String password;

    @Bean
    public Connection getCPEConnection() {
        try {
            Connection conn = Factory.Connection.getConnection(url);
            Subject subject = UserContext.createSubject(conn, username, password, "FileNetP8WSI");
            UserContext uc = UserContext.get();
            uc.pushSubject(subject);
            System.out.println("CE Connection" + conn);
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in my RestController this is how I am trying to access the Bean method getCPEConnection() return value:

```
@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

public FilenetConnection getBeanOfBaseComponent() {
    return applicationContext.getBean(FilenetConnection.class);
}
```

Now everytime I access the bean method's return value using `getBeanOfBaseComponent().getCPEConnection()` a new object for conn from the (Singleton) @Bean getCPEConnection() is returned. What I am missing here?

Comment: Replace `@Component` with `@Configuration` and just inject the `Connection` instead of the configuration of the context. As soon as you start doing things like `getBean` and you are not writing a library/spring extension stop coding, take 3 steps back and think, then think some more and make really really really sure you need it like that. Generally you are doing the wrong if you need this.

Comment: Using @Configuration is refusing to read url, username and password values.

Comment: Then you are doing things really wrong not sure why. But the fact that you try to solve it like this is solving the wrong thing. If `@Configuration` doesn't work, `@Component` shouldn't work either (as an `@Configuration` is also a specialized `@Component`).

Comment: Thats what my confusion is now. Why its behaving like that.

Comment: The that is the fact that you use `getBean` that is already an indication. For the full answer, I have no idea as there is far too little information. The `@Configuration` should just work (at least if you use the correct annotation, not sure if there are other packages containing that as well). Your `@Bean` method is flawed as well, you shouldn't catch the exception and return `null` just let it blow up.

Comment: @Configuration is working fine too. But still the conn object is not singleton.

Comment: The `@Configuration` makes it a specialized class with some additional proxying to make it a singleton. If it isn't you are doing things in a way that is wrong, but as we don't know that (too little information). And as stated you should be using `@Autowired` for the `Connection` instead of the `getBean` you do now.

Answer (score 2):

So I understand that you do something like this:
You call `getBeanOfBaseComponent()` and there you get the Instance of FilenetConnection and on this instance you call `getCPEConnection()`.
If I understood this correct it makes sense that it doesn't work.
Because you don't use the bean you just call a normal method which returns you a new Instance of `Connenction`.

So I don't use this way of accessing beans myself but I guess you need to use `applicationContext.getBean(Connection.class);` to be able to use the `Connection` bean.

Or another and easier solution would be to just inject the Connection into your Controller class.

And normally you define beans in classes annotated with `@Configuration` and not `@Component`

Comment: Use `@Configuration` on `FilenetConnection` instead and simply inject `Connection` on service layer with `@Autowired`

Comment: Connection is an interface not a class. - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=comfilenetapicore-connection

Comment: That's no problem. `.class` works on interfaces too!

Comment: My bad for overlooking. You are right. I was missing import. Trying now. Thanks.

Comment: Dw I hope it works! :D

Comment: Didn't work. :-(

Comment: Did you try to use injection instead of the application context?